# How can artillery.io load testing be distributed across multiple cores

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, load-testing, artillery

It is likely realized when attempting to run larger scale tests with artillery.io that high CPU warnings will be displayed. As this technology runs a node process to drive test scenarios defined in yaml scripts, the single-core process can attempt to push so much throughput before lacking in CPU resources. A quick Google search will bring about the following result describing some features within artillery to distribute artillery scenarios across multiple cores, https://artillery.io/blog/artillery-20-preview-multicore, but unfortunately does not seem to be the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the test cases [here](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/blob/master/test/testcases/errors-and-warnings.bats). The way to enable the feature: e.g. `MULTICORE=1 ARTILLERY_WORKERS=4` followed by the rest of the command to run your artillery test.

Comment: The link doesn't work. Really curious about how to do this. Any refs would be welcomed.

Comment: @QualiT looks like there have been some changes within artillery since I last looked at this. first you can see the commit here that removes the test from the previous link. https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/blob/f2d3085a3aa8ecf3d04d471d461f5d787767b626/packages/artillery/test/cli/errors-and-warnings.test.js. second here's an issue that references >= v2 has this built in by default. https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/81#issuecomment-964961484